# Remote file not opening with RemoteApp program

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2008-r2, remoteapp

On Windows Server 2008 R2 I have configure a .jar file as a RemoteApp program, and am executing it remotely (outside our network) on Windows 8.

Without RemoteApp, the program normally creates an .html file when we need to print something. It temporarily stores the file in a directory and opens it with the default browser.

So, when I use my RemoteApp, the file is saved in the directory (on the server) and a browser opens on my local computer which attempts to load the file, but it never ends up loading.

The browser that opens appears to be a RemoteApp application itself (it has the little <> rdp symbol over its normal icon in the toolbar), although I never created a RemoteApp application for this browser.

I'm not sure how opening files that are on the server is supposed to work. The only information I've come across is in regards to a RemoteApp program's ability to open when a file type it is capable of opening is opened, on the local computer.

Comment: RemoteApp supports opening apps that are not published on the server side. Easiest example - in your JAR app window, press Ctrl-Alt-End, open Task Manager, File, New Task, iexplore.exe. Are you sure that the path is correct? What is the error in the remote IE window? I believe this is not an RDP-specific problem.

Comment: My default browser was Chrome which works fine on the server without RemoteApp. Switching the default to IE loads the file just fine. I was under the impression that deploying RemoteApps is a way to restrict access to other resources on the server. Originally I thought the issue was that I didn't have the same path and file on my local computer, so I created the path, shared my local drive, and set up the file's directory on the server as a symbolic link pointing to the local directory I created. This didn't work, obviously, then I noticed the browser was a remote rdp app. @cdavid -- Thanks!